# Docker-compose and nginx lead to connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream error

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I run and application and nginx in docker containers and struggle to get it running:

This is my nginx.conf

```
server {

    server_name data-mastery.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://shinyproxy:4000;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/nginx/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;

    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}

server {
    if ($host = data-mastery.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name data-mastery.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  shinyproxy:
    build: ./shinyproxy
    container_name: shinyproxy
    expose:
      - 4000
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./shinyproxy-logs/server:/log"
      - "./shinyproxy-logs/container:/container-logs"
      - "./shinyproxy:/opt/shinyproxy"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - shinyproxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

Building the images worked correctly, however when I run `docker-compose up`, nginx spits out the following error `nginx         | 2021/06/27 07:16:37 [error] 22#22: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.157.1.112`

I thought this might happen, because nginx should have to wait for the shinyproxy app, so I added a `depends-on`, but this did not solve my issue.

Does anyknow know where my Problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as so often, when you ask a question, you find the answer 5 minutes later:

The shinyproxy application has got a `yaml` file where you also have to set a port which I had to overwrite:

```
proxy:
  port: 4000
```